# Accessing Plone site from python keyword library

Tags: plone, robotframework

I am using plone.app.robotframework.  I have created a keyword library class in Python, and it works fine for simple jobs.

How can I access the objects in the Plone site, from these keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `getSite()` or `plone.api.portal.get()` to get your portal object :

```
from plone import api
portal = api.portal.get()
```

Comment: Thanks - this works fine if bin/test is used to run the tests.  In other or odd situations, the keyword library needs to be configured as a remote library.